# Rails rendering only certain fields in nested associations of a model as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model, associations, render

I'm building an API which has a Studio(cinematic), a Studio has movies and movies have characters and also have genres. I've already built all the models and they seem to be working as expected. Now i'm trying to build my GET (index) of all the movies in my MoviesController but i'm having a problem.

My MoviesController is as follows:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
def index
    render json: Movie.all, only: [:title, :date_released, :score], include: [:studios, :characters]
end
end
```

This way i am able to render all my movies as json, and i get only the fields title, date_released and score, and also render the associated fields Studio and Characters. My problem is that Studios and character render themselves ENTIRELY(id, name, created_at, updated_at). I only want to render Studio's name and characters names, not their id's nor created date. I have been unsuccesful to apply the same "only: [name:] " to studios nor characters. How can i achieve this?

Thank you for your help. If you have any advice on how to make my code better, please say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
render :json => Movie.all, only: [:title, :date_released, :score], include: {studios: {only: :name}, characters: {only: :name}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can go to sleep now (2am here). It worked flawlessly and will serve my purposes. There's so little information on these matters on the internet. Saved me!